# TypeScript allow implicit cast between two types

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
interface A {
    readonly value: number;
}

function f(a: A) {
    if (a.value === 1) {
        // compiler error that 2 cannot be assigned to a
        // a = 2;
        // no compiler error
        a = 2 as unknown as A;
        // a.value will now return 2
    }
}
```

Is it possible, without explicit casting, to allow this conversion between interface A and number to happen implicitly?  Basically add some type information to the A interface to say that a number can always be assigned to this type?

My JavaScript runs in a non-standard environment (Salesforce Commerce Cloud / Demandware) where operator overloading is supported, so assigning a number to the property ends up creating a new object for that property -- not actually changing the property itself to a number (so later you can still read the property as the original object type).

If I could say that function argument "a" is interface A when reading, but number when writing/assigning to, that would also work -- but pretty sure that isn't possible yet, separate types for read/write.

Sorry if already asked or wrong place to ask.  All conversations I've found related to this are people that desire TypeScript to be able to support run-time code for this type of thing.  I don't want to change my run-time code or add any new features, I just want to be able to correctly define what existing run-time code is already doing.

Comment: Since this is not standard behavior Typescript does not offer any support for it. There is no way to define such a conversion.. Maybe if `A` extended Number.. But that is not really the behavior you are describing

Comment: Probably your best bet is to wait till different types for getters and setters are supported https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2521. I don't see a way to support your requirement with what is already available.